# possibly left join with column value manipulation and condition check

Tags: sql, join, left-join

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field_id = t2.field_id 
WHERE t2.field_id IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

- I'm trying to get the `field_value` from `table 1` that does not exist in `table 2`
- And add the row in table 2 and set `is_selected = 0`

I tried with join on `t1.field_id = t2.field_id` and `t1.value_id != t2.field_value_lookup`

```
Table 1             
value_id    field_id    title       
25            14    readonly1       
26            14    readonly2       
27            14    readonly3       
1             13    optionA     
2             13    optionB
```

Table 2

```
user_id   field_id  type_id field_value_lookup  is_selected
260073      14       11       26                  0
260073      14       11       27                  1
```

Expected result in Table 2

```
user_id    field_id type_id field_value_lookup  is_selected
260073         14     11            26            0
260073         14     11            27            1
260073         14     11            25            0
```

Comment: We greatly prefer text so we can copy/paste to help you out.  Also, you are not clear on what you want to actually *do*.  I *think* you're looking to `update` the `is_selected` column?

Comment: Please post sample data with expected results to help you. Images are good to know but would involve a lot of effort to reproduce the output.

Comment: my apology this is my first post here. I am trying to get the missing values from table 1 compared to table 2 for a matching field_id (table 1 and table 2) then add a value 0 in in_selected column for the retrieved missing values

Comment: output section  is the expected result i am looking for. thanks for your help and quick response

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "add a value".  Are you expecting *modify* the table?  OR do you just want the results to show 0?

Comment: i want to modify the table 2 by adding the missing field_value from table 1 and have 0 in the is_selected column for the added row

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Presuming Microsoft SQL Server*

**untested**

```
select t2.user_id, t2.field_id, t2.type_id, t1.value_id field_value_lookup, 0 is_selected
from ( -- get the distinct existing information from table2 without field_value_lookup
   select distinct user_id, field_id, type_id
   from table2
) t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.field_id = t2.field_id -- add all the values from table1
where not exists (select 1 -- exclude the rows that already exist
                  from table2
                  where user_id = t2.user_id
                     and field_id = t2.field_id
                     and type_id = t2.type_id
                     and field_value_lookup = t1.value_id
                  )
```

Comment: No problem.  It too me a bit to understand what you wanted.